# Hive External Table exclude records that violate data type

Tags: json, hadoop, hive

I have an external table in Hive that uses a serde to process json records. Occasionally there will be a value that does not match the table ddl data type, e.g. table field definition is int, json has a string value. During query execution Hive will correctly throw this error for metadata exception due to type mismatch:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: 
Hive Runtime Error while processing writable
```

Is there a way to set Hive to just ignore these records that have data type violations?

Note the json is valid syntax, so settings the serde properties like to ignore malformed json is not applicable.

Example DDL:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_tbl (
acd         INT,
tzo         INT
 )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
;
ALTER TABLE test_tbl  SET SERDEPROPERTIES ( "ignore.malformed.json" =  "true");
```

Example data - the TZO = alpha record will cause the error:

```
{"acd":6,"tzo":4}
{"acd":6,"tzo":7}
{"acd":6,"tzo":"alpha"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up Hive to tolerate a configurable amount of failures.

```
SET mapred.skip.mode.enabled = true;
SET mapred.map.max.attempts = 100; 
SET mapred.reduce.max.attempts = 100;
SET mapred.skip.map.max.skip.records = 30000;
SET mapred.skip.attempts.to.start.skipping = 1
```

This is not Hive specific and can be applied to ordinary MapReduce as well.

Comment: still i am getting an issue while inserting data from one hive table top another table.
i am trying to copy data (more then 300 million rows) from hive table to Elasticsearch using this query:- insert overwrite table TableNameES select * from HiveTableName;

& after inserting some of rows i am getting this exception. i know this is because of different data type of mapping in ES ...

i want to skip inserting those row which one giving error not only this exception may be other exception.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to handle this in hive yet.   I think you may need to have an intermediate step using MR, Pig etc. to make sure the data is sound and then input from that result.

There may be a configuration parameter here you could use
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties#ConfigurationProperties-SerDes

I'm thinking you may be able to write your own exception handler to catch that and continue by specifying your custom handler with hive.io.exception.handlers

or if you are ok storing as an ORC file instead of a text file. You can specify the ORC file format with HiveQL statements such as these:

```
CREATE TABLE ... STORED AS ORC
ALTER TABLE ... [PARTITION partition_spec] SET FILEFORMAT ORC
```

And then when you run your jobs you can use the skip setting:

```
set hive.exec.orc.skip.corrupt.data=true
```